# What is the general procedure to run WRF-chem with chen_opt=16

Tags: climate-change, wrf, wrf-chem

Is there anybody who has run WRF-chem with `chem_opt=16` successfully to simulate the green house gases? According to the User guide, it can be done in this way. But the detail is vague. Even the `auxinput15_inname`, which is the format of input file, could not found explanation.

Hence, any body can give me advice? If possible, a `namelist.input` may be great helpful.

=============================update 2018.03.22============================

I still don't konw about the auxinput15.

BUT, in my case, I use  `auxinput5_inname='wrfchemi_d<domain>_<date>'`  for anthropogenic CO2 emission, and the other option about CO2 is set `16`.

Comment: probably a question better suited for http://forum.wrfforum.com/

Comment: @farrenthorpe maybe you should stick to links redirecting you to another SE site, rather than a random site.